# When is SeTcbPrivilege used? ("Act as part of the operating system.)

Tags: winapi, privileges

For what purpose(s) is the `SeTcbPrivilege` privilege in Windows used? Can it be used, for example, to run a program under the SYSTEM account?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Acting as a part of the operating system allows you to do things like create login tokens. It's unlikely that you would ever need to write a service that uses this privilege unless you're writing an authentication provider.

Since you can create access tokens, you can act as any user. Of course, this means that you can run programs under the SYSTEM account, but there are much easier ways to run something as SYSTEM.

Comment: +1 Oh, interesting! (I'd ask what the easier ways are, but that's a different question.) :) Is login-related functionality generally the only thing it lets you do, or are there other things as well? (I'm asking because "act as part of the operating system" sounds really broad, more broad than just authentication scenarios.)

Comment: TCB stands for Trusted Computer Base, meaning it's the part of the system that is responsible for security.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Gabe's answer, here is what MS says,

> Allows a process to assume the identity of any user and thus gain
>   access to the resources that the user is authorized to access.
>   Typically, only low-level authentication services require this
>   privilege.
>
> Default setting: Not assigned.
>
> Note that potential access is not limited to what is associated with
>   the user by default; the calling process might request that arbitrary
>   additional privileges be added to the access token. The calling
>   process might also build an access token that does not provide a
>   primary identity for tracking events in the audit log.
>
> When a service requires this privilege, configure the service to log
>   on using the Local System account, which has the privilege inherently.
>   Do not create a separate account and assign the privilege to it.

Source: [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457125.aspx#EAAA)

Answer (score 0):

SeTcbPrivilege is very useful for debugging purpose. For example, if you are developing Windows service that has to be run under system account and perform  impersonate things it is conveniently to run this service as standalone exe. SeTcbPrivilege will allow to do this.